# easy thing about clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

According to the results I am getting ( I do not see that in the API), hclust works by using each row of a given matrix as a vector. Is there any way to work it so that it works with columns instead?

Besides, does dist work the same or does dist work with columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always apply hclust to transposed matrix:

```
# If you have observations matrix 
m <- matrix(1:100, nrow=20)
hc <- hclust(dist(t(m)))
```

> Besides, does dist work the same or does dist work with columns?

General convention is variables in columns, observations in rows and that's how dist works:

```
dist                   package:stats                   R Documentation

Distance Matrix Computation

Description:
This function computes and returns the distance matrix computed by
using the specified distance measure to compute the distances
between the rows of a data matrix.
```

**Update**

> hclust works by using each row of a given matrix as a vector.

Actually internal implementation of hclust shouldn't matter. You pass as an argument dissimilarity structure produced by dist, and I am almost sure, that all metrics implemented in dist produce proper symmetrical distance matrix.

Comment: actually it does matter. My data, being example data, where pretty obvious and without the transformation you mentioned I did get a totally wrong tree.

Comment: If you transpose your data before computing distance matrix it of course matters. Most of the time you'll get different distance matrix. But that’s not what I meant. Distance matrix is symmetrical and that's what goes to the hclust. Basically  all what happens inside hclust is searching for closest clusters and joining them. And it doesn’t matter if you search by row or column.